# zfcUser, BjyAuthorize, doctrine orm not working -error: ServiceManager::unable to fetch ObjectManager

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, bjyauthorize

i am trying to use  [BjyAuthroize](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize) with my [zfcUser](https://github.com/gianarb/ZfcUser) and [doctrine 2 ORM](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2)

as the clue to bind doctrine to bjyauthorize i used 
i use the module [samUser](https://github.com/manuakasam/SamUser)

in my

however i am getting the following error messages;

> Uncaught exception
>   'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message
>   'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create
>   an instance for My\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager' in
>   C:\wamp\www\testChat\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php

in my config authoload bjyauthorize.global.php file

```
return [
    'bjyauthorize' => [

        // set the 'guest' role as default (must be defined in a role provider)
        'default_role' => 'guest',

        /* this module uses a meta-role that inherits from any roles that should
         * be applied to the active user. the identity provider tells us which
         * roles the "identity role" should inherit from.
         * for ZfcUser, this will be your default identity provider
        */
        'identity_provider' => \BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\ZfcUserZendDb::class,

        /* If you only have a default role and an authenticated role, you can
         * use the 'AuthenticationIdentityProvider' to allow/restrict access
         * with the guards based on the state 'logged in' and 'not logged in'.
         *
         * 'default_role'       => 'guest',         // not authenticated
         * 'authenticated_role' => 'user',          // authenticated
         * 'identity_provider'  => \BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\AuthenticationIdentityProvider::class,
         */

        /* role providers simply provide a list of roles that should be inserted
         * into the Zend\Acl instance. the module comes with two providers, one
         * to specify roles in a config file and one to load roles using a
         * Zend\Db adapter.
         */
        'role_providers' => [

            /* here, 'guest' and 'user are defined as top-level roles, with
             * 'admin' inheriting from user
             */
            \BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\Config::class => [
                'guest' => [],
                'user'  => ['children' => [
                    'admin' => [],
                ]],
            ],

            // this will load roles from the user_role table in a database
            // format: user_role(role_id(varchar], parent(varchar))
            \BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ZendDb::class => [
                'table'                 => 'user_role',
                'identifier_field_name' => 'id',
                'role_id_field'         => 'role_id',
                'parent_role_field'     => 'parent_id',
            ],

            // this will load roles from
            // the 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ObjectRepositoryProvider' service
            \BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ObjectRepositoryProvider::class => [
                // class name of the entity representing the role
                'role_entity_class' => 'My\Role\Entity',
                // service name of the object manager
                'object_manager'    => 'My\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager',
            ],
        ],

        // resource providers provide a list of resources that will be tracked
        // in the ACL. like roles, they can be hierarchical
        'resource_providers' => [
            \BjyAuthorize\Provider\Resource\Config::class => [
                'pants' => [],
            ],
        ],

        /* rules can be specified here with the format:
         * [roles (array], resource, [privilege (array|string], assertion])
         * assertions will be loaded using the service manager and must implement
         * Zend\Acl\Assertion\AssertionInterface.
         * *if you use assertions, define them using the service manager!*
         */
        'rule_providers' => [
            \BjyAuthorize\Provider\Rule\Config::class => [
                'allow' => [
                    // allow guests and users (and admins, through inheritance)
                    // the "wear" privilege on the resource "pants"
                    [['guest', 'user'], 'pants', 'wear'],
                ],

                // Don't mix allow/deny rules if you are using role inheritance.
                // There are some weird bugs.
                'deny' => [
                    // ...
                ],
            ],
        ],

        /* Currently, only controller and route guards exist
         *
         * Consider enabling either the controller or the route guard depending on your needs.
         */
        'guards' => [
            /* If this guard is specified here (i.e. it is enabled], it will block
             * access to all controllers and actions unless they are specified here.
             * You may omit the 'action' index to allow access to the entire controller
             */
            \BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller::class => [
                ['controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index', 'roles' => ['guest','user']],
                ['controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'stuff', 'roles' => ['user']],
                // You can also specify an array of actions or an array of controllers (or both)
                // allow "guest" and "admin" to access actions "list" and "manage" on these "index",
                // "static" and "console" controllers
                [
                    'controller' => ['index', 'static', 'console'],
                    'action' => ['list', 'manage'],
                    'roles' => ['guest', 'admin'],
                ],
                [
                    'controller' => ['search', 'administration'],
                    'roles' => ['staffer', 'admin'],
                ],
                ['controller' => 'zfcuser', 'roles' => []],
                // Below is the default index action used by the ZendSkeletonApplication
                // ['controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index', 'roles' => ['guest', 'user']],
            ],

            /* If this guard is specified here (i.e. it is enabled], it will block
             * access to all routes unless they are specified here.
             */
            \BjyAuthorize\Guard\Route::class => [
                ['route' => 'zfcuser', 'roles' => ['user']],
                ['route' => 'zfcuser/logout', 'roles' => ['user']],
                ['route' => 'zfcuser/login', 'roles' => ['guest']],
                ['route' => 'zfcuser/register', 'roles' => ['guest']],
                // Below is the default index action used by the ZendSkeletonApplication
                ['route' => 'home', 'roles' => ['guest', 'user']],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

`My\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager` is just a placeholder for whatever service you will use.

Where you write you are using Doctrine, you need to specify whatever your object manager is called.

For example, you could probably use
`doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default`

Once you fix this, you will probably notice that you have other placeholders in there too.  For example, My\Role\Entity.

I recommend you take a good look at:
https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize

Good luck!  This at least, will fix your object manager naming issue.